# Robolectric 3 with Fabric Crashlytics

Tags: android, unit-testing, robolectric, robolectric-gradle-plugin, crashlytics-android

I am trying to ShadowClass Crashlytics/Fabric so that Robotlectric 3 tests do not fail.  What I have so far is this:

The custom test runner that adds the Shadow class for Fabric:

```
public class TestRunner extends RobolectricGradleTestRunner {
    public TestRunner(Class<?> klass) throws InitializationError {
        super(klass);
    }

    @Override
    protected ShadowMap createShadowMap() {
        return super.createShadowMap()
            .newBuilder().addShadowClass(ShadowFabric.class).build();
    }

    @Override
    public InstrumentationConfiguration createClassLoaderConfig() {
        InstrumentationConfiguration.Builder builder = InstrumentationConfiguration.newBuilder();
        builder.addInstrumentedClass(ShadowFabric.class.getName());
        return builder.build();
    }
}
```

The shadow class for Fabric:

```
@Implements(Fabric.class)
public class ShadowFabric {
    @Implementation
    public static Fabric with(Context context, Kit... kits) {
        System.out.println("Shadowing Fabric");
        return null;
    }
}
```

My application class for my app:

```
public class MyApp extends Application {
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        setupCrashlytics();
    }
    protected void setupCrashlytics() {
        Crashlytics crashlyticsKit = new Crashlytics.Builder().core(new CrashlyticsCore.Builder().disabled(BuildConfig.DEBUG).build()).build();
        // Initialize Fabric with the debug-disabled crashlytics.
        Fabric.with(this, crashlyticsKit);
    }
}
```

And here is the test that passes in Debug (because Crashlytics is disabled on it), but fails in release mode because the ShadowClass is not working correctly:

```
@RunWith(TestRunner.class)
@Config(constants = BuildConfig.class, sdk=21, packageName="com.my.release.package.name", shadows={ShadowFabric.class})
public class MyTest {
    @Test
    public void testGreenDAOsave() {
        // blah
    }
}
```

The error I get with Crashlytics / Fabric during the test is the following:

```
STANDARD_ERROR
io.fabric.sdk.android.services.concurrency.UnmetDependencyException: com.crashlytics.android.core.CrashlyticsMissingDependencyException:
This app relies on Crashlytics. Please sign up for access at https://fabric.io/sign_up
install an Android build tool and ask a team member to invite you to this app's organization.
```

The stack trace shows that MyApp.setupCrashlytics() is being called and Fabric.with() is failing.

1) YES, the app is registered with Crashlytics.

2) YES, I did contact Crashlytics support email.  I was told 'Robolectric is not supported'.

From what I can see, I just need to get the shadow class thing working and then Crashlytics will get shadowed and not init'd.

Ideas / Help would be very much appreciated!

Comment: try Fabric.class instead of ShadowFabric.class at `builder.addInstrumentedClass(ShadowFabric.class.getName());`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is my usual advice how to write a test against something not testable.

Extract you **Fabric** initialisation to protected method:

```
public class <MyApplicationName> {

public void onCreate() {
   initFabric();
}

@VisibileForTesting
void initFabric() {
....
}
}
```

Create `Test<MayApplicationName>` class in test sources (same package and override **Fabric** initialisation:

```
public class Test<MyApplicationName> {
void initFabric() {
//nothing to do
}
}
```

Everywhere where you need using **Fabric** use DI (Dependency Injection) to mock **Fabric** in tests. Even more, I would suggest you create Analytics/Crash/Distribution class and hide **Fabric** usage from entire application.

And final you have left classes that wrap/hide the **Fabric**. Here you can write a custom shadow, spy on the real object or leave it untested. And you already tried to write custom shadow without success, also, spying is not an option here.

Happy coding!